# One user sponsoring gas fees for another user

Tags: gas

I'm currently working on developing an election DApp that will have two types of users: voters and election creators. I want to include gasless transactions in this DApp, but I also want to make it so that the election creator can sponsor the gas cost for the voters, instead of me as the deployer and contract owner sponsoring it.

I'm hoping to get some help on how to achieve this. If you have any suggestions or ideas, I would really appreciate it! Thank you in advance.

Comment: With upcoming [Ethereum account abstraction](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/what-is-ethereum-erc-4337-account-abstraction) this will be easier. However, please note that the full account abstraction rollout may last years to come.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta transaction , to enable the election creator to sponsor the gas cost for the voters, you can use a smart contract to manage the election. The contract can include a function that allows the election creator to deposit Ether into the contract, which can be used to pay for the gas fees for the voters. You can also add a mechanism for the election creator to withdraw any unused Ether after the election is over.

When a voter submits a transaction, they can include a meta transaction that specifies the election creator as the sponsor. The contract can verify the signature and deduct the gas cost from the election creator's deposited Ether.

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to make it so that the election creator can sponsor the
> gas cost for the voters, instead of me as the deployer and contract
> owner sponsoring it.

This can be done by creating a separate gas tank and asking the creator to provide funds there to enable gasless txns.

I would recommend you check out the [Gelato](https://gelato.network/) docs.

You can do various things like choose which users should be getting gas-less and which should not. Also there are options for gasless wallets.

Cheers!